# ASP.NET MVC: How to return multiple responses?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a MVC application that is intended to show a message to the caller (in their browser as html), as well as provide a file download.

Is it possible to trigger a popup window that initiates the file transfer, while providing a html response in the calling window?

Project is using C#, with only very basic customisations on the sample project.

Thanks!

Comment: You would return a complex type for the model

Comment: I solved this by adding some javascript to the cshtml file, causing a popup to occur on another route, which downloaded the file.

Comment: This sounds really hacky. If you have some code I might be able to help more

Comment: This should NOT BE CLOSED. The other question runs into a similar problem, but it has complicating issues this one does not.